# Which melee weapon, other than Zenith, has the highest DPS?

Tags: terraria, terraria-mobile

I would like to know which weapon I should use, other than Zenith. I’m looking for a melee weapon with the highest damage per second.

Comment: Isn't that completely up the situation, character, playing style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really hard to know for sure because there are so many variables, like buffs, number of enemies, etc. Going off of raw damage only, the Meowmere has the highest Damage per attack, but it is much slower than Zenith. But the highest damage output ever was not recorded with a high-damaging weapon.

There is an [exploit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6a2bAEs86KE) with the Shadow Jousting Lance and an Inner Tube that allows for damage numbers well into the billions. It does so much damage, the DPS counter underflows into the negatives.